# Dual Basis problem

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I've been dealing with this but I haven't been able to understand the underlying principles of dual basis, so i don't know how to do it well. It starts like this:

Have $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ basis of the tridimensional space $V_3$. And be:
$$
e'_1=2e_1-e_2+e_3\\
e'_2=e_1+e_2-e_3\\
e'_3=e_1+2e_2+e_3
$$

1. Prove $(e'_1, e'_2, e'_3)$ is a basis of $V_3$. (I don't know if proving that the transformation from e' to e is linearly independent could do the job).
2. Find the relationship between the dual basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and $(e'_1, e'_2, e'_3)$ (Is is just putting $(e'_1, e'_2, e'_3)=(e_1, e_2, e_3)*P$ where P is a 3x3 matrix described by the transformation above).
3. How does covector $\phi =e_1-e_2+2e_3$ is written in the base $(e'_1, e'_2, e'_3)$?

I sincerely thank you. I wrote the entire problem but if you can help me with anything (Maybe 1st one, I have no idea how to prove this!) I would be very pleased. Thank you and good day!

Comment: Why do you say "dual basis"? You are just considering 2 basis of a given vector space $V_3$, and not $V_3$ with its dual $V_3^{*}$. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Hello! Well, if we are talking about part (b) I'm referring to basis $e_i$ for V3 and $e'_i$ for V*3

Comment: Hallo!Uhm...but I do not understand why should $e^{'}_i$ be in the dual space $V_3^{*}$ as it is presented as a linear combination of basis elements in $V_3$. In 1. you want to prove it is a basis in $V_3$, while in 2. you talk about duals: would you like to introduce the dual basis to $e^{'}_i$ in $V_3^*$, instead?

Comment: Yes I understand, it may be a mistake in the statement. As I got it , it gives me a relationship between $e'_i$ and $e_i$ but I think what I'm asked for is about $V_3$, which base is $e_i$ and, if you're right (I think it makes total sense), the statement of part (a) should say "...is a basis of $V*_3$". Nevertheless, this is my statement in case you understand spanish (I translated it very carefully) [link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/91l2fa.jpg).

Comment: I think the translation is perfect :-). I think the problem really boils down to "find the matrix of change of basis" and "determine a given vector w.r.t. another base", all in $V_3$.

Answer (score 1):

for $(a)$, we can do the linear combinations:

$\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2)=e_1$, $\frac{1}{3}(e'_2+e'_3)-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2)=e_2$, and $e'_3-2(\frac{1}{3}(e'_2+e'_3)-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2))-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2)=e_3$

So by a linear combination, we can form the original basis, so they must themselves be a basis.

for $(b)$:

$(e'_1,e'_2,e'_3)^T= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \end{array} \right](e_1,e_2,e_3)^T$

(its much nicer to think of a left matrix)

for $(c)$

$\phi=e'_1-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2)+2(\frac{1}{3}(e'_2+e'_3)-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2))e'_3-2(\frac{1}{3}(e'_2+e'_3)-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2))-\frac{1}{3}(e'_1+e'_2)$

(this probably simplifies more but i'll leave that to you.

Comment: Hello ellya, thanks for your answer. I wanted to ask you how did you get the coefficients for the equations of (a)? I inverted the matrix P and i got \begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ \frac{-2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{9} & \frac{-5}{9} & \frac{1}{3} \end{array}, maybe i missed something!

Comment: I think you are right, the only thing is I didn't bother to simplify my answer!

Comment: Did my answer suffice?